# How to append a list of arrays onto a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, lapply, cbind

I have the following list.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 1)
df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 2)
df3 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 3)
df4 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 4)

ls_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

And, I also have another list of arrays.

```
a1 <- rep(1, 10)
a2 <- rep(2, 10)
a3 <- rep(3, 10)
a4 <- rep(4, 10)

ls_a <- list(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

I want to replace column `a` in each data frame in `ls_df` such that `ls_df[[1]]$a` contains 1's, `lf_df[[2]]$a` contains 2's, and so on.

I tried the following... apparently not working as intended.

```
ls_df <- lapply(ls_df["a"], function(x) ls_a)
```

Help, please??

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Map` :

```
ls_df <- Map(function(x, y) {x$a <- y;x}, ls_df, ls_a)
```

The same can be done with `map2` from `purrr`.

```
purrr::map2(ls_df, ls_a, ~{.x$a <- .y;.x})
```

You probably mean `a1` to `a4` of length 10 and not 20 since number of rows in `ls_df` are 10.

```
a1 <- rep(1, 10)
a2 <- rep(2, 10)
a3 <- rep(3, 10)
a4 <- rep(4, 10)
ls_a <- list(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

Comment: Functional version: `Map(function(x, y) transform(x, a = y), ls_df, ls_a)`

Answer (score 1):

Not as succinct as @Ronak Shah's Map function:

```
ls_df <- lapply(seq_along(ls_df), function(i){
    ls_df[[i]]$a <- i; return(ls_df[[i]])
  }
)
```

Using Map:

```
Map(function(i){ls_df[[i]]$a <- i; ls_df[[i]]}, seq_along(ls_df))
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 1)
df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 2)
df3 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 3)
df4 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), vector = 4)
ls_df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```